# How can I find out which digit is different between two numbers in Python?

Tags: python, algorithm

Assume that we are given two numbers, `1873` and `183`.
Is there a way that we can find what digit is different between these two numbers in a way faster than O(n) in python?

All I could think of is the following solution:

```
def difference_1(num1, num2):
  for digit in str(num1):
    if digit not in str(num2):
      return digit
```

This looks very sub-optimal to me due to the type casts and the O(n^2) complexity.
I couldn't think of any other way since I need to check every digit, so I need an iterable object hence the `str` type casting.

Is there any other way to achieve the same result with a better performance and a more idiomatic way?

Notcied some ambiguity in my question.
Here is the most important constraint:
Num2 is always a variation of Num1 with one missing digit.
I am trying to find the missing digit.

Some test cases:
Num1, Num2, Result
1234, 123,  4
1223, 123,  2
987, 87, 9

Comment: The complexity of your approach is O(n^2)

Comment: Right. Thanks for pointing it out @RiccardoBucco.
 `if digit not in str(num2)` is looking up a list, which is `O(n)` itself. Forgot about that, will edit the description

Comment: Currently you're repeatedly converting `num2` to a string, and then looking through it to see if it contains a given digit. Use a set instead, and only create it once.

Comment: What output would you want if the numbers were 123 and 122?

Comment: @GeoffreyBrent Thanks for pointing out the ambiguity, I added the main constraint, and also a few test cases.

Comment: @khelwood Good point about repeated casting, Don't think I can use a set though, it won't work if num1 has repeated digits: `num1=1223, num2=123` then the num1 set would be `123`, and we can't detect the missing digit anymore

Comment: I only said use a set for the digits in `num2`. If you care about repeats in `num2`, then your current code does not work either. E.g. `difference_1(1223, 123)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
from itertools import zip_longest

def difference_1(num1, num2):
    return next(d1 for d1, d2 in zip_longest(str(num1), str(num2)) if d1 != d2)
```

This has a linear complexity in the worst case (i.e., the last digit is the one that is missing).

```
>>> difference_1(1873, 187)
'3'
>>> difference_1(1234, 123)
'4'
>>> difference_1(1223, 123)
'2'
>>> difference_1(987, 87)
'9'
```

You can also use `zip` if you don't want to use `zip_longest`:

```
def difference_1(num1, num2):
    return next((d1 for d1, d2 in zip(str(num1), str(num2)) if d1 != d2), str(num1)[-1])
```

Comment: This only works if `num1` is the longer and `num2` is the one with a missing digit...

Comment: @dawg if you read the description, that's exactly what the user asked for :) "num2 is always a variation of num1 with one missing digit"

Answer (score 0):

Compare digits?

```py
def f(n1, n2):
  while n1 and n2:
    d1, d2 = n1 % 10, n2 % 10
    if d1 != d2:
      return d1
    n1, n2 = n1 // 10, n2 // 10
    if not n2:
      return n1

ns = [
  (1873, 187), # 3
  (1234, 123), # 4
  (1223, 123), # 2
  (987, 87) # 9
]

for n1, n2 in ns:
  print(f(n1, n2))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `Counter` since subtraction is supported.

1. Convert the number to a string;
2. Sort by length;
3. Subtract the shorter from the longer.

Here:

```
from collections import Counter

def missing_int(x,y):
    shorter,longer=sorted(map(str, [x,y]),key=len)
    return list((Counter(longer)-Counter(shorter)).keys())[0]
```

You can test:

```
cases=[
    (1234, 123, 4),
    (1223, 123, 2),
    (987, 87, 9)
]

for x,y,ans in cases:
    print(missing(x,y))
```

Prints:

```
4
2
9
```

Since `sorted` by `len` is used, this works regardless which is the longer number.

---

If the first number is always the longer, you can simplify a little:

```
def missing_int(x,y):
    longer,shorter=map(str, [x,y])
    return list((Counter(longer)-Counter(shorter)).keys())[0]
```